# Restart Observable connected to a resource

Tags: scala, rx-scala

In the following code I turn a TCP socket into an `Observable[Array[Byte]]`:

```
import rx.lang.scala.Observable
import rx.lang.scala.schedulers.IOScheduler

val sock = new Socket
type Bytes = Array[Byte]

lazy val s: Observable[Bytes] = Obs.using[Bytes, Socket] {
  sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.0.2.2", 9002), 1000)
  sock
}(
  socket => Observable.from[Bytes] {

    val incoming = socket.getInputStream
    val buffer = new Bytes(1024)

    Stream.continually {
      val read = incoming.read(buffer, 0, 1024)
      buffer.take(read)
    }.takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)

  },

  socket => {
    println("Socket disposed")
    socket.close
    s.retry // Does not work
  })
  .subscribeOn(IOScheduler.apply)

s.subscribe(bytes => println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8")), println)
```

Connection to a remote server may be interrupted at any moment and in that case I'd like an `Observable` to try to reconnect automatically but `s.retry` does not do anything. How can I achieve this? Also can it be done "inside" the current `Observable` without creating a new one and re-subscribing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set up a new socket connection on each new subscription. This is easiest with `(A)SyncOnSubscribe`, ported to RxScala since version `0.26.5`. One you have this observable you can use normal error control methods like `.retry`.

Something like this:

```
val socketObservable: Observable[Byte] = Observable.create(SyncOnSubscribe.singleState(
  generator = () =>
    sock
      .connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.0.2.2", 9002), 1000)
      .getInputStream
)(next = is => Try(is.read()) match {
    case Success(-1) => Notification.OnCompleted()
    case Success(byte) => Notification.OnNext(byte)
    case Failure(e) => Notification.OnError(e)
  },
  onUnsubscribe = is => Try(is.close)
)
```

Note: this reads a single byte at a time and isn't terribly efficient. You can improve this with ASyncOnSubscribe or having each event of your observable be an array of bytes.

Note: this is a cold observable and will create a new socket for each subscriber. For example this will open 2 sockets:

```
socketObservable.foreach(b => System.out.print(b))
socketObservable.buffer(1024).foreach(kiloByte => System.out.println(kiloByte))
```

If this is not what you want you can turn it into a hot one with `.share`